# Reason for boolean switching when minifying js

Tags: javascript, minify

I have this line of code in a js file

```
var useScroll = Window.innerWidth > 1360 ? true : false;
```

When it's minified it becomes

```
i=Window.innerWidth>1360?!0:!1
```

I was just curious, why have the `!` operator? To me it makes more sense to just be.

```
i=Window.innerWidth>1360?1:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very valid reason. `1` and `0` are integeers, and does sometimes behave different than booleans.

However the `!` operator includes casting, which menas that `!0` and `!1` are acutal booleans, but they are shorter to type than `false` and `true`. And that is the reason they are beeing used.

Example where they behave different:

```
var a = (1 === true); //a will be false
var a = (!0 === true); //a will be true
```

However you can simplify your code to

```
i=Window.innerWidth>1360
```

since `Window.innerWidth>1360` will be either `true` or `false` which is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The `!` operator does casting. So `!0` becomes `true` and `!1` becomes `false`. However, `0` and `1` are numbers, not booleans.

Answer (score 2):

if you do `!0` or `!1` it will become a boolean, if you remove `!` it will be an integer...

And instead of doing

```
Window.innerWidth > 1360 ? true : false
```

do

```
Window.innerWidth > 1360
```

Comment: Best answer so far!

Answer (score 2):

The **! is (logical NOT)** operator So !0 become true and !1 becomes false. Where only 0 and 1 are numbers not boolean.

```
var n1 = !true;  // !t returns false
var n2 = !false; // !f returns true
var n3 = !'Cat'; // !t returns false
```

So, both have a different meaning by data types.

**i=Window.innerWidth>1360?1:0** This is also valid as you told but when you want data type as boolean you can't get by using this expression.