# Is it safe to use integers (1, 0) instead of booleans (true, false) to minify JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, boolean, minify

When JavaScript is used client-side, it has to be transferred over the network, which is why we commonly [minify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) the code, for example by removing whitespace and shortening identifiers (variable and function names, etc).

In JavaScript / ECMAScript, many functions will accept a `boolean` to trigger certain behavior. For example, [`DOMTokenList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) or [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Using the integers `1` and `0` instead of the boolean values `true` and `false`, respectively, when calling upon such functions would save some additional bytes.

However, JavaScript has two comparison operators, `==` and `===`, and while `1 == true` would evaluate to true, `1 === true` would evaluate to false. Then again, maybe the standard dictates that built-in functions have to be able to deal integers when accepting a boolean or similar. **In short, is it safe to replace booleans with integers in the context of built-in functions?**

Comment: Safe is a squishy word. One person's "safe" is another person's "crazy risky". I would say you could depend on something like `!0` (on its own) always being evaluated as `true` and `!1` always being evaluated (by itself) as `false`.

Comment: Both examples are not part of ECMAScript but are part of the Web spec. And there's a lot of legacy semantics involved. `JSON.stringify(false)` returns something different than `JSON.stringify(0)`

Comment: Unless you analyze the code and check all the places that use the value, so you can tell whether it just checks its "truthiness" or performs type-specific checks, you have to be conservative in your transformations.

Comment: Related / possibly duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567523/javascript-minification-why-is-false-replaced-with-1-and-true-with-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381308/reason-for-boolean-switching-when-minifying-js/48381354

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the built-in function. For some, passing an integer produces the same result as passing a boolean, for others it doesn't. In general, yes, if a function expects a boolean it will attempt to coerce any value into a boolean, but there are probably exceptions.

However, a minifier does in general not know whether a function call is a call to a builtin function, or what the function's signature is. The first goal is to be correct (not introducing bugs), not to output the smallest bundle.

A standard trick that minifiers *do* employ, and which is always equivalent, is replacing `false` with `!1` and `true` with `!0`.